# How to set slideshow to image?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is make a slideshow full of text, however, I'm having struggles with making the first "slide" of the slideshow show only by itself, and not display the others when the page is initially loaded.

At the moment, I've got this code for my slide show

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

          <div class="mySlides fade">

            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>

            <div id="section1" class="prescroll-section"></div>

            <div id="about-section1">

            <p id="about-header1">Lorem Ipsum Times</p>

            <img id="hand-down1" src="../assets/hand-down.png"> 

            <p id="about-description1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sagittis nibh elementum vehicula molestie. Donec in vehicula orci. Praesent imperdiet, dolor quis consequat cursus, elit purus mattis dolor, quis tempus nisl odio eu nisi. Morbi eget porta elit. Phasellus non neque vel neque elementum mattis elementum quis quam. Ut hendrerit lorem quis velit luctus condimentum. Donec dui nibh, consectetur eu nisi in, euismod molestie massa. Duis et justo ipsum. Nulla ornare risus vestibulum, imperdiet justo non, finibus ante.</p>

            <img class="about-image-1" src="../assets/smaller-about-description1-image.png">

            <div class="about-divider"></div>

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">

            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>

                            <div id="section1" class="prescroll-section"></div>

            <div id="about-section1">

            <p id="about-header1">Lorem Ipsum Times</p>

            <img id="hand-down1" src="../assets/hand-down.png"> 

            <p id="about-description1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sagittis nibh elementum vehicula molestie. Donec in vehicula orci. Praesent imperdiet, dolor quis consequat cursus, elit purus mattis dolor, quis tempus nisl odio eu nisi. Morbi eget porta elit. Phasellus non neque vel neque elementum mattis elementum quis quam. Ut hendrerit lorem quis velit luctus condimentum. Donec dui nibh, consectetur eu nisi in, euismod molestie massa. Duis et justo ipsum. Nulla ornare risus vestibulum, imperdiet justo non, finibus ante.</p>

            <img class="about-image-1" src="../assets/smaller-about-description1-image.png">

            <div class="about-divider"></div>

          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">

            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>


          </div>


        </div>

        <div id="dot-row" style="text-align:center">

          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 

          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 

          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 

        </div>
```

With CSS set to:

```
.mySlides {
display: none;}
```

Obviously, this will make the images hidden by default. To try something different I just completely removed it, but this then shows all the slides. Is there any way that I configure the CSS so that it will only show the 1st slide by default?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of active class, with the first block having the active class and then swapping it, Or you can make use if any available plugins or bootstrap carousel

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp